# httpd.conf match absolute file

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, files, httpd.conf

I have the following directory statement in my httpd.conf for a virtualhost.

```
<Directory c:/foo/bar/*/*/baz>
    <Files index.php>
        # something file specific
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

This matches "c:/foo/bar/ * / * /baz/index.php" but also "index.php" in subdirectories..

I would like it to only match "index.php" directly within /baz (e.g. absolute file path), any ideas?

Im relatively new to server configuration so its a bit trial and error for me. (Wamp installation on windows 7 64bit)

**Edit**

I just realize i could do something like;

```
<Directory /foo/bar>
    <Files index.php>
        # something file specific
    </Files>
    <Directory /*>
        <Files index.php>
            # revert/undo something file specific
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Untested though, but should work in theory, right?

**Edit 2**

SOLVED! <Location /index.php> seems to does the trick...

Comment: yes, create an answer, but I wouldn't accept <Location> if I were you as it is parsing the URI instead of the directory structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the location attribute - that might be where your problem is.